# Integrate Silverlight4 application with asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0, ria, wcf-ria-services

I made one application in silverlight4 and used EDM and WCF-RIA for database access.

Now I want to integrate this application to asp.net project and when I integrate it into the ASP.net project it is giving this exception-

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Load operation failed for query 'GetQuestions'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound.   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c_*DisplayClass1b.b*_17(Object )

so please help me anybody.

Comment: How are you adding the server-side RIA services SERVER-SIDE code to your ASP.Net application?

Comment: i have just added .xap file in asp.net application and copy the code of(only body part) .aspx page of silverlight application and paste it into asp.net .aspx page  but i don't know how to add that domain services files in asp.net application??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RIA Services DomainService has 2 parts. You have copied the client part by virtue of copying the XAP file, but you are missing the RIA WCF server-side part of the service.

You need to move the Domain service files from your original Silverlight website to your new ASP.Net project (along with any web.config settings required to wire it up properly). *This is not in the ASPX files.* Without seeing the specifics of your existing projects I can't tell you exactly what filenames you need to migrate.

My suggestion is to *always* create RIA Service libraries instead of adding directly to a Silverlight application. Then you can link the Client-side library to any number of Silverlight applications, then link the .Web part of the RIA library to your website to provide the WCF service. Again the key is to migrate the config settings.

It will probably make a lot more sense if you create a new RIA services *library project*, add your EDM etc, then link the halves to a separate Silverlight app and your new ASP.net website.

### Step-by-step:

1. Create RIA Services Library project by selecting *Add New Project*. Select *Silverlight* on the left. Select *WCF RIA Services Class Library* on the right. I will assume it is called the default name *RIAServicesLibrary1* for this example. It will create a Silverlight client library called RIAServicesLibrary1 and a standard .Net library called RIAServicesLibrary1.Web for use by the Web server.
2. Add your EDMX to the `RiaServices.web` project. Select *Add new item*. Select *Data* on the left. Select *ADO.Net Entity Data Model* on the right. I will assume it is called the default `Model1.edmx` for this example. Connect it to your database tables etc.
3. Build your project so that the next step will find your data model.
4. Create a Domain Service referencing your EDMX models in your `RiaServices.web` project. Select *Add new item*. Select *Web* on the left. Select *Domain Service Class* on the right. I will assume it is called `DomainService1.cs` for this example. Choose your data items from the *Add New Domain Service Class* popup window by ticking the checkboxes. A set of RIA services objects and methods will be created for each item you select.
5. Add a reference to the client Ria services library project (*RIAServicesLibrary1*) to your Silverlight application.
6. Add a reference to the web RIA services library project (*RIAServicesLibrary1.Web*) to your hosting web application (e.g. you ASP.Net website).
7. Copy/merge the various sections in the RIAServicesLibrary1.Web/app.config file into your <webapplication>/web.config file. This will include any connection strings and the module sections.
8. Build the project again so that the Data Source window will see your new Domain Context data sources.
9. Use the `RIAServicesLibrary1` client object (called DomainService1 in this example) directly from your Silverlight code like this:

   DomainService1 client = new DomainService1();

or use the `Data Sources` window to drag/drop a new grid etc onto a page.

If the `Data Sources` window is not visible select the "Data" menu then the "Show Data Sources" option.

For more information try this Microsoft link: [Using WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/silverlight-4/using-wcf-ria-services/)

Comment: thanks for your  response but still how to create RIA Service library and where i include this library. my main motto to use silverlight application with asp.net project and that silverlight application will use domain service for data accessing. so please exaplain me the way to do these thing acconding to your RIA service library.

Comment: @Pappu: Updated answer for you. If you need more detail let me know which specific areas.

Comment: ya i have already completed my application on that way that you have mentioned , everything is working fine but the problem start when i want to add this application with my existing project(ASP.net) then it is throwing an exception that i have mentioned .so my point is how to add these domain service class of Sl application into ASP.net project because i just copied the .xap into Asp.net project..so what to do now??

Comment: @Pappu: It sounds like you are still only doing half the steps. Have you added a reference to the RIA services ".web" project to your ASP.net website? Have you added the config settings from RIA ".web" project's app.config into your ASP.Net website's web.config?

Comment: please help me how to add these things ? i am very new in silverlight.

Comment: @Pappu: The instructions above are about as clear as I can get without seeing your actual project. Please follow them step by step. If you still cannot fix it contact me via my website (on my profile) and I will fix it for you.